# How to set userid into a session array in codeigniter?

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, session

I'm a bit new to Codeigniter, so I need some help, please if you can just post here the answer. Thank you.

Here is my **Controller:**

```
public function login()
{

    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|valid_email|min_length[3]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('passwd', 'Passwd', 'required|min_length[3]');

    $data = array();

    if ($this->form_validation->run())
    {
        $email = $this->input->post('email');
        $passwd = $this->input->post('passwd');

        $this->load->model('user_model');

        if ($this->user_model->check($email, $passwd))
        {

            $this->session->set_userdata('user', $email);

            redirect(base_url('/'));
        }
        else
        {
            $data['error'] = 'Wrong e-mail or password.';
        }
    }

    $this->load->view('login', $data);
}
```

and here is my **Model:**

```
public function __construct()
{
    // Call the CI_Model constructor
    parent::__construct();
}

public function check($email = NULL, $password = NULL)
{
    $this->db->select('id');
    $this->db->where('email', $email);
    $this->db->where('password', sha1($password));
    $this->db->limit(1);
    $result = $this->db->get('php_users_login');

    return ($result->num_rows() == 1);
}
```

I would like to put user-id into the session (database structure like id, email, password...)

Thank you for helping!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

**Model**

```
$this->db->select('id');
$this->db->where('email', $email);
$this->db->where('password', sha1($password));
$this->db->limit(1);
$result = $this->db->get('php_users_login');
return   $result->row();
```

**Controller**

```
$checkData=$this->user_model->check($email, $passwd);
if(count($checkData)==1){
   $this->session->set_userdata('user_id', $checkData->id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

**In Controller**

```
public function login()
{

    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->load->model('user_model');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|valid_email|min_length[3]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('passwd', 'Passwd', 'required|min_length[3]');

    $data = array();

    if ($this->form_validation->run())
    {
        $email = $this->input->post('email');
        $passwd = $this->input->post('passwd');         

        $result = $this->user_model->check($email, $passwd);

        if ($result == true)
        {
            $newdata = array(
               'email'     => $email,
               'logged_in' => TRUE
           );

            $this->session->set_userdata($newdata);

            $this->load->view('home', $data); # load view
        }
        else
        {
            $data['error'] = 'Wrong e-mail or password.';
            $this->load->view('login', $data);
        }
    }
    else{
        echo "Form validation Error";
    }

}
```

**In model**

```
public function check($email, $password)
{

    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM php_users_login WHERE email = '$email' AND password = sha1('$password') ");
    $result = $query->result_array();

    $count = count($result);

    if (empty($count) || $count > 1 ) {
        return false;
    }
    else{
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: This gives me the else statement (Form validation Error)

Answer (score 0):

You can set userid in session as:

Use this in your model:

```
public function check($email = NULL, $password = NULL)
{
    $userid = 0;
    $this->db->select('id');
    $this->db->where('email', $email);
    $this->db->where('password', sha1($password));
    $this->db->limit(1);
    $result = $this->db->get('php_users_login');

    if($result->num_rows() == 1){
        $data = $query->result_array();
        $userid = $data[0]['id'];
    }
    return $userid;
}
```

**In Controller:**

```
// if login successfull
$this->load->model('user_model');
$userid = $this->user_model->check($email, $passwd);
if ($userid > 0)
{
    // session array
    $session_data = array(
           'session_userid'  => $userid,    
           'session_email'  => $email
           );

    $this->session->set_userdata($session_data);
    redirect(base_url('/'));
}
else
{
    $data['error'] = 'Wrong e-mail or password.';
}
```

**Side Note:**

I didn't see session library included in your code, make sure you are using in autoload.php or included in the same controller.

```
$this->load->library('session');
```